# How do i call out according to the id when i click on specific row in my table form?

Tags: php, sql-server

This is the code where i select the button but it keep retrieving the first id even when i click on second id.

```
include "lib/mssql.connect.php";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_adminip WHERE id =  id";

    // run the query
     $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
     if($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
        ?>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class=" col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                    <legend>Edit IP</legend>
                    <p id="details"></p>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal fade"  id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Duty Officer</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div id="display">
                            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">ID</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">

                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtid" value="<?=$row['id'] ?>" disabled="">
                                </div>
                                <label for="inputIP" class="col-lg-2 control-label">IP Address</label>
                                <div id="ip" class="col-lg-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtName" value="<?=$row['adminip']; ?>" placeholder="IP" data-content="Please enter your IP Address" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="AccountInfo()">Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Use while loop as  `while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {` instead of `if condition`

Comment: @Saty Hi it is not making any difference (: any other solution?

Comment: What is your query `    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_adminip WHERE id =  id"; is your `id is id`???
`

Comment: Can you suggest a query if i want to retrieve a data from tbl_adminip base on a primary key which in this case is id. It will be helpful.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tbl_adminip WHERE id = 1`

Comment: But what if the admin user click on the id for 2 ,3 and so for? It will then retrieve the id 1 since the sql query states (SELECT * FROM tbl_adminip WHERE id = 1). That is my current problem now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your using if statement instead of looping through the data you have fetched from the `database`. Try out this

```
include "lib/mssql.connect.php";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_adminip WHERE id =  id";

// run the query
  $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
 //if($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
   while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) 
    {
    ?>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class=" col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                <legend>Edit IP</legend>
                <p id="details"></p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade"  id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Duty Officer</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div id="display">
                        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">ID</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-10">

                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtid" value="<?=$row['id'] ?>" disabled="">
                            </div>
                            <label for="inputIP" class="col-lg-2 control-label">IP Address</label>
                            <div id="ip" class="col-lg-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtName" value="<?=$row['adminip']; ?>" placeholder="IP" data-content="Please enter your IP Address" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="AccountInfo()">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi i don't think changing to while is working. It still retrieving the only the first id in the table

Comment: What are you trying to archive, fetching all data which are in `tbl_adminip` table. Or you want to get a specified data by using `ID`

Comment: Trying to fetched a specific data using ID from tbl_adminip (:  @little-phild

Comment: Where is `id` coming from

Comment: it is a primary key in tbl_adminip

Comment: I know in your query `$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_adminip WHERE id =  id";`, First `id` is a primary key what about second `id`. Where is it coming from

Comment: Can you suggest how should i write my sql query if i want to retrieve a specific row base on id from tbl_adminip after a user selects on a button.. @little phild

Comment: That's the right query but I don't where your getting `id` value is coming from. Maybe your getting the same `id` value. First specify for me where are you getting `id` value

Comment: i did not declare the second id anywhere. Basically that particular query is the same as $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_adminip WHERE id = 1"; which id 1 is taken from database right away. i am guessing here i'm missing some steps like $POST to declare the id? can you suggest? Thanks (: @little phild

Comment: Alright now I understand where the problem comes from.  So you just estimate the `id` value.

Comment: Any sql query suggestion? @little phea

Comment: In order for someone to pull the data  what are you basing on.

Comment: Am going to write for you a query but I need more clarification @stewart .

Comment: a button from a table form (<td><a data-toggle="modal" onclick = "openConfirmDialog(<?=$guestbook[$i]['id'] ?>)" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Edit</a></td>) @little phild

Comment: Alright: Now I know but every data you  edit should have a unique `id` which is the `primary key` where are you storing that `id`

Comment: I know before you edit a specific data you should first pull it  from the `database`.

Comment: Is `$guestbook[$i]['id']` a unique `ID` of every data.

Comment: i think no. Maybe i can get your email? so i can show you more of the codes to help me? (: @little phild

Comment: That's it but please just delete the above comment. I mean my email